# autoplay video on Android 4.2.2 with fullscreen google chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-video, autoplay, android-fullscreen

I am working on a project where I am using a set-top-box (Geniatech ATV1220) to display one website (http://goo.gl/1SckBk) on which there are some webkit transitions and other stuff like a video in a carousel.

The box is running Android 4.2.2 and it will only display the site correctly when I use the Google Chrome Browser (v34). The only problems I have with it, is that the Android Google Chrome doesn't have a kiosk mode and that autoplay of the video tag is not supported by intent, so I have to "click" manually to start it. Once I activated it, it will play without a problem in the next rounds of the carousel.

Is there any way to toggle the fullscreen API or get the video to automatically play without user interaction?

If I use the tag

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

and then add a site to homescreen I still have the android status bar with the clock and I don't want that. So that is sadly not an option.

I was also thinking about maybe using Webview, since it gives you the option to remove the need of user interaction to play a video, but after my first tries it also didn't display the site correctly, probably because it is not using the chrome webkit version.

Before I dig deeper into it and maybe try to work with chromeview or something I wanted to ask if anyone had some similar needs and could guide me in the right direction on how to continue.

Thanks in advance,
egon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building a custom chromium content shell with the needed features.

For the fullscreen I did as explained here:
[kiosk mode or fullscreen in chromium on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450183/kiosk-mode-or-fullscreen-in-chromium-on-android)

For the autoplay you have to set m_userGestureRequiredForPlay in the HTMLMediaElement.cpp to false:

```
if (document.settings() && document.settings()->mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture())
    m_userGestureRequiredForPlay = false;
```