# kiosk mode or fullscreen in chromium on android

Tags: android, fullscreen, chromium, kiosk-mode

I have built a chromium ContentShell for my android device as explained here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions

I now want to use this ContentShell in fullscreen mode. I tried to add the flag kiosk as explained here:

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags

But it is not working. Is there a way to use kiosk mode on android with chromium or would you recommend another way to achieve what i want to have? (display of website in fullscreen without any address bar/menu and also no system ui bars)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get rid of the system UI bars I did this:

```
service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui
```

As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19373504/3640770

Then I edited shell_view.xml and added this to the LinearLayout responsible for the toolbar:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

As explained here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/6sSGXfPOhqg